# Expander transform the text vertically

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have **Expander** in my application set *FlowDirection* as right its working well, but the header text is showing in Horizontal direction. I would like to show the header text draw vertically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LayoutTransformer` from sl toolkit

```
<xmlns:layout="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit">
<toolkit:Expander.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <layout:LayoutTransformer>
            <layout:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </layout:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>

            <TextBlock Text="Some Text"  />
        </layout:LayoutTransformer>
    </DataTemplate>
</toolkit:Expander.HeaderTemplate>
```